# MYSQL: Syntax error: 'DELETE' is not valid input at this location

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my first time attempting to do a transaction and I want to make a transaction to delete all German ships from the classes table and also add a new USA ship into the table at the same time.

```
START TRANSACTION
-- Delete Germany from classes table
DELETE FROM classes WHERE country = 'Germany';
-- Add new ship for USA into classes table
INSERT INTO `classes` (`class`,`type`,`country`,`numGuns`,`bore`,`displacement`) 
VALUES ('SS Farkas','bb','USA','10','20','36000');
-- Commit the transaction
commit;
```

I'm getting this syntax error upon trying to execute at the beginning of my DELETE FROM statement:

> Syntax error: 'DELETE' (delete) is not valid input at this position

Comment: Missing a semicolon. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Just a remark: `numGuns`,`bore`,`displacement` are probably/hopefully numeric columns, then you should provide numeric data, not strings: `VALUES ('SS Farkas','bb','USA',10,20,36000)`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `;`:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- Delete Germany from classes table
DELETE FROM classes WHERE country = 'Germany';
-- Add new ship for USA into classes table
INSERT INTO `classes` (`class`,`type`,`country`,`numGuns`,`bore`,`displacement`) 
VALUES ('SS Farkas','bb','USA','10','20','36000');
-- Commit the transaction
commit;
```

Comment: Updated . for missing reason